# How can I set up django with apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, django

I am new in django/python. I am currently using django's in-built server for development.

I want to configure apache to run django. As with some google search, I found that I need mod_wsgi, which I have installed on my windows 10.

However putting django in htdocs is still not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that mod_wsgi.dll is loaded in apache module, in apache config.

After that make the following changes in apache config

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/venv
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

You can read more from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/